# Script files are not loading in javascript for safari browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, safari

I am developing a website. In the navbar, I need to set the username for every page. So I take a .js(app.js) file and wrote some in it and calling that file on every page. I placed that file in my public folder like pages. It's working fine in chrome browser. But it comes to safari the file is not loading. I declared the file like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
```

What modifications do I need to do?

Below are the screenshots of the logs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you determining that it isn't loading? Have you checked the Network tab in the developer tools? Is it giving an error instead of the 200 OK status and the script?

Comment: Looks like `app.js` is being successfully loaded from the cache. There's no sign of a problem.

Comment: Does the cached response contain the data you expect?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: "I don't think so" — You seem unsure. Use the Network tool to *look* and be sure.

Comment: I didn't find any in the Network tab. I am new to the safari.

Comment: Click on the line where app.js is listed!

Comment: Yeah, it's opened my app.js file. I have put some console.logs in that file. Even those logs are not displaying in the console tab.

Comment: So you're just looking at a cached version of it. Do a hard refresh.

Comment: Yeah, I identified my issue. In my second screenshot, it's an error for firebase messaging. In my app.js file that's the file line and the remaining logs are next. I commented that messaging package and its working fine. Thank you for your time @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified my issue. In my second screenshot, it's an error for firebase messaging. In my app.js file that's the first line and the remaining logs are next. I commented that a messaging package and its working fine. Our script file must be error-free.